# How to count python list members more efficiently

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

i have created a list of words used in spam emails having  320571 entries. now i need to find out the frequency of each word.I have written the following code but it takes too much time(very very very much).

```
%%time
flat_ui=[]
for i in range(len(biggie_spam)):
    temp=biggie_spam.count(biggie_spam[i])
    flat_ui.append(temp)
```

how can this be done more efficiently?

Comment: I suggest taking look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a solution using a **map-reduce** approach. [Here](https://gist.github.com/antoineleclair/2008789) you have a simple example of a word count algorithm using the map-reduce algorithm in Python.

You can find plenty of information, but [this tutorial](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) could be a starting point.